# How can I send a php function an array like {28:1,29:0,30:1}?

Tags: php, arrays, object

I have set up an onclick to send a javascript function an array like this {28:1,29:0,30:1}.

I am wondering how I can send that to the php function so that when it is received, it is recognized as an array, rather than the form that it is in now.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to transform your original string to array in php you can try

```
$str = '{28:1,29:0,30:1}';

$array = explode(',', trim($str, '{}'));
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $x)
{
    list($key, $value) = explode(':', $x, 2);
    $result[$key] = $value;
}
```

`echo "<pre>"; print_r($result);` will give you

```
Array
(
    [28] => 1
    [29] => 0
    [30] => 1
)
```

**[Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qGxKnQ)**

Comment: @DanielFain Do you need more help with the question?